# Code pulsemeter with NodeMCU esp-12

Tags: firebase, arduino, nodemcu

I try to follow this [Heart rate using nodemcu](https://www.hackster.io/kuncono/online-heart-rate-monitor-using-nodemcu-and-cayenne-e332ee), (change Cayenne for Firebase), but I have problems with the Interrupt.ino (I try to change pulsemeter sample code, and have the same problem); is not compatible with Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E-Module)"

When I choose Board:"Arduino Genuino/Uno" the program compiles OK, but I can't use the mcu to connect with Firebase.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Change the interrupt.ino of the original project https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensor_Amped_Arduino
for this project interrupt.ino https://github.com/EnvironmentMonitor/Pulse-Sensor-ESP8266-ADC0, the problem; I see is because the Arduino work with timers but the nodemcu not.